# Python Regex to findall lines contains specific type of filenames

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a text file. I want to get the lines that contain a file-name only if the file-name is a .doc or a .pdf type file.

For example,

```
<TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">4.</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>L. Sam</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">5.</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>G.K. Ram</TD>
</TR>
```

using python `re.findall()` I want to get the following lines.

```
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>
```

Can any body please tell me any scalable way to define the pattern in the re.findall()?

Comment: like `href=".+?\.(doc|pdf)`

Comment: its returning ['pdf', 'doc'] only....But I need whole line....

Comment: try it with `search`, not `findall`

Comment: Statutory warning: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1321855). (That shouldn't be a problem with this simple example, though.)

Comment: are you suggesting to loop through the lines and search each one of them???findall actually does that in an efficient manner provided we are giving it the correct pattern...

Comment: @mxant: do you want to explain me how regexes work? ;)

Comment: @thg435: nah..not necessary...thanks anyways...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
(.*?<a\shref=[\"']\w+(?:\.doc|\.pdf)[\"']>.*)
```

Output:

```
>>> html = """<TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">4.</TD>
... <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>
... <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>L. Sam</TD>
... </TR>
... <TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">5.</TD>
... <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>
... <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>G.K. Ram</TD>
... </TR>"""
>>> re.findall("(.*?<a\shref=[\"']\w+(?:\.doc|\.pdf)[\"']>.*)", html)
['<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>', '<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>']
```

Comment: But I need the whole line...from <TD ...> to </TD>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> strs="""<TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">4.</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>L. Sam</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">5.</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=72>G.K. Ram</TD>
</TR>"""

>>> [x for x in strs.splitlines() if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(pdf|doc)",x)]
['<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="ABC.pdf"> On Complex Analytic Manifolds</a></TD>',
 '<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH=50%><a href="DEF.doc"> On the Geometric theory of Fields</a>*</TD>'
]
```

Comment: actually I don't want to use string functions... I need to do it using regex only...

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `BeautifulSoup` and `re`.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

lines = soup.findAll('href', text = re.compile('your regex here'), attrs = {'class' : 'text'})
```

with `class` your upper level header in the html code.